# JScolor picker doesn't with chrome extension page action html

Tags: html, google-chrome-extension, jscolor

page action html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="jscolor.js"></script>
        <script src="popup.js"></script>

        <style>
            body{
                min-width: 250px;
                min-height: 150px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>

        <button
    class="jscolor {valueElement:null,value:'66ccff'}"
    style="width:50px; height:20px;"></button>



    </body>
</html>
```

This html works just fine as just a web page. But when I use it as chrome extension page action html, the styles all messed up. Why is this? Do I need to include the source file in manifest.josn as well?

Answer (score 0):

Two fixes are needed to solve your problem:

```
src="jscolor.js"></script>
```

there should be slash before script name:

```
src="/jscolor.js"></script>
```

And also you have to specify in your manifest file:

```
    "web_accessible_resources" : [
        "jscolor.js",
        "popup.js"
    ],
```